# control animationDrawable with gesture

Tags: android, animation, drawable, gesture

I'm currently working on AnimationDrawable and i was wondering if every drawable items can be controlled by swipe right and left gesture to perform rewind and forward.and it should halt if no gesture is detected.

Thanks in advance.

here is my imageview and animationdrawable code:

```
    imageView1 =  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rotate_animation);
    animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable)imageView1.getBackground();
    animationDrawable.start();
```